# How to check field in django model?

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model like this. I want to check if the name of the team will be "Russia", then you need to specify the name of the team.

I want to check when a user enters data into a form.

How can I check?

```
RUSSIA = 'RUS'
USA = 'USA'
GERMANY = 'GER'


COUNTRY = (
    (RUSSIA, "Russia"),
    (USA, "USA"),
    (GERMANY, "Germany"),
)


class Country(models.Model):

    country = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRY, default=RUSSIA)
    name_of_team = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name_of_team
```

Comment: When do you want to check this? In a form?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, it's not entirely clear what you are asking. Are you trying to validate input? If there is some related form you use to make the `Country` please include that.

Comment: I want to check when a user enters data into a form. @shuttle87

Comment: It sounds like you need a modelform with custom validation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use the `clean` method of a `ModelForm` for the `Country` model:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Country, RUSSIA


class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Country

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        country = cleaned_data.get('country')
        name_of_team = cleaned_data.get('name_of_team')

        if country == RUSSIA and not name_of_team:
            self.add_error('name_of_team', 'You must supply a team name')

        return cleaned_data
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other for more information on form validation.

I would also recommend moving the choice constants inside the `Country` model for clarity:

```
class Country(models.Model):

    RUSSIA = 'RUS'
    USA = 'USA'
    GERMANY = 'GER'


    COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
        (RUSSIA, "Russia"),
        (USA, "USA"),
        (GERMANY, "Germany"),
    )

    country = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES,
        default=self.RUSSIA)
```

then in your form you can do:

```
. . .

def clean(self):
    . . .

     if country == Country.RUSSIA and not name_of_team:
        self.add_error('name_of_team', 'You must supply a team name')

    return cleaned_data
```

This is largely a matter of personal preference, but it offers better readability in my opinion.